# Ubuntu 22.10 cannot execute x32-ABI binaries

Tags: 22.10

Ubuntu 22.10 (amd64) cannot execute any x32 binaries on my freshly installed computer (x32: x32-ABI, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI). Example program helloworld.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
int main(argv) { printf("Hello World.\n"); }
```

The resulting binary fails as follows (also if the binary was produced on older Ubuntu versions):

```
# gcc-12 -mx32 -o helloworld helloworld.c
# ./helloworld
-bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

If I try the resulting binary on 22.04 or any older Ubuntu version, it works as expected.
My foreign architectures look fine:

```
# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Is there a relevant change from 22.04 to 22.10?

Comment: The official update info. https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-in-ubuntu-desktop-22-10-kinetic-kudu

Comment: @David Thanks. But I can't find any mentions of x32? Do you mean any linked reference?

Comment: Which means no one on this site most likely knows. I suggest you file a bug report. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with different kernel versions and checked their `/boot/config-...` files. Ubuntu has removed the kernel option `CONFIG_X86_X32` in the 5.19 kernel of Ubuntu 22.10 (the mainline kernel ppa shows the same for versions 5.17, 5.18, 6.0). Hence, x32 binaries cannot be run from 5.17 on and Ubuntu 22.10 has a 5.19 kernel. That is a pity.

I filed a bug on launchpad against the kernel package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1994516

Unfortunately, this bug is marked as "Won't Fix". So, we will switch our compute cluster to another Linux distribution.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there *are* no kernel packages for 6.0 in Ubuntu yet so there is nothing worth reporting here for "6.0".  The latest kernel as you indicated is 5.19, and nothing has 6.0 kernels yet.  Your question for 'alternative kernels' is not an answer, though, and was removed because the rest of your answer is in fact an answer.